# Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) unable to connect to “Personal Hotspot” on an iPad running iOS 8

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, bluetooth, ios, ipad

After I moved over to a new user account on my Mac—to try to fix another issue—my Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and iOS 8 “Personal Hotspot” function quit working.

At first it wouldn’t show my iPad’s availability at all. But after deleting the Mac OS X keychain and resychronizing with iCloud Keychain, I could see my iPad in the Wi-Fi network list as an available “Personal Hotspot” once again but I still couldn’t actually connect to the “Personal Hotspot” on my iPad.

The error that would eventually pop up would be:

> Failed to enable Personal Hotspot on [Device]. Check to see if the
>   tethering device is turned on and in range of your computer.

I tried turning on and off Bluetooth, deleting my iPad from Mac OS X's Bluetooth preferences, etc… to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Klein posted [a solution on the Apple Support Community](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26903860#26903860) that did the trick:

> 1. Sign out of the iCloud account on both devices. (I let iCloud delete everything when asked. It all comes back when sign back in later)
> 2. Reset Network Settings on the iPhone (General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings)
> 3. If necessary, Rename the phone to what you want it called (General -> About -> Name. Resetting network settings consistently renamed my phone to just “iPhone”)
> 4. Power down both devices.
> 5. Restart iPhone and log back in to iCloud.
> 6. Restart other device and log back into iCloud.

I had my doubts as to whether this would actually fix a personal hotspot issue, but I’m happy to report it did. I hope it helps someone else, too.

Comment: While this works for a while, my Personal Hotspot feature always eventually stops working, usually after several days.

Comment: In my case is stops basically next time I want to use it, so in few hours. Do we know what is the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just **signing out of iCloud on the Mac** then connecting to the hotspot prompted for a password, when it hadn't been prompting for password before.  I was then able to connect

My iPhone was replaced entirely by Apple Support so a new Hotspot password was generated - I'm guessing iCloud had an old copy of the password and wasn't realizing that that one didn't work and it needed a different pwd.

Comment: This worked for me, basically instantly. When I signed out of iCloud on my Mac, my phone moved from the 'Personal Hotpsot' section of the WiFi dropdown menu and into the wifi networks. I could then connect and things started working immediately.